# Why is this OutOfMemoryError not showing up when thrown by a Future?

Tags: java, concurrency, out-of-memory

A simple scenario:

```
private static final ExecutorService executor =
        Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

public static void main(String... args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    Future<byte[]> f = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        f = executor.submit(new Callable<byte[]>(){
            @Override
            public byte[] call() {
                System.out.println("Starting task.");
                try {
                    return new byte[1500 * 1024 * 1024];    // 1500 mb
                }
                finally {
                    System.out.println("Task complete.");
                }
            }
        });
    }
//  System.out.println(f.get().length);
}
```

When I run the above code it (allegedly) runs without error.

(Strangely, an *OutOfMemoryError* is being thrown when I profile this code in NetBeans, but not when I run it normally.)

All 10 "Task complete." messages immediatelly show up, in a time-frame far too short for the byte arrays to be actually allocated.

When I uncomment the last line an *ExecutionException* is thrown.

I know the code example is kind of absurd...
But why is no exception at all being thrown and how can I make the *OutOfMemoryError* show up? Do I have to catch it? Would that be a safe operation?

Comment: Always catch exceptions. No exceptions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't catch `Errors` - they're intended to noisily crash your program.  You should only catch an `Exception` if a. you're logging it / re-throwing it or b. you're handling it; there's no way for you to handle an `OutOfMemoryError`, so let it crash your program like it's supposed to.

"Task Complete" is showing up when the `Future` objects have been allocated, not when they're done with their work - you need to call `f.get()` on each Future to ensure that it's finished allocating its byte array.  The program runs slower when you're profiling it, which allows for more `Futures` to allocate their byte arrays before the Main method terminates, which in turn allows them to use up all of your heap space.

Change `f` to an ArrayList of futures (and `f = executor.submit` to `f.add(executor.submit)`), then iterate through it and call `.get()` on all of its futures. That should trigger your OutOfMemoryError without using the profiler.

Comment: There are *some* circumstances where it's reasonable to handle allocation failure and thus an `OutOfMemoryError`.  For example, you might ask for a giant buffer, but back off to a small one if there's not enough room.  I found the rest of your answer enlightening.  Thanks for posting.

Comment: @Zim-Zam O'Pootertoot I was under the impression that the try-finally block establishes a happens-before relationship. But it seems you are corrent.

Comment: @JanKebernik - happens-before is not terminology thats normally associated with a try/catch block. But the reason why your finally block is being executed first is because your entire call method is effectively a one-liner, with the one line being the *return expression*. And the finally block gets executed before return expressions are evaluated. More detail [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.17).

Answer (score 0):

Main thread will not become automatically aware of exceptions throws by threads. 
Previous run method was used which doesn't throw exceptions and you were forced to use uncaughtexceptionhandler.

JDK1.5 onwards futures and callables were introduced. Call method of callables throws exception as well as returns a values. Now to catch the exception thrown by call method you need to call future.get().

So your code is working perfectly.